# Whats wrong with my Nhibernate HQL query?

Tags: nhibernate

I have this

```
public List<TableA> GetRecords(List<string> keys)
    {
        const string query = "FROM TableA WHERE `Key` = :keys";
        return session.CreateQuery(query).SetParameterList("keys",keys).List<TableA>().ToList();
    }
```

I get it could not execute error "could not execute query"

when I look at it my where clause is always equal to "?" . So it's like not using my list to fill it in.

**Edit**

If I have this

```
List<strings> myKeys = new List<strings> {"1", "2"};
GetRecords(myKeys)
```

It will fail

If I have

```
List<strings> myKeys = new List<strings> {"1"};
GetRecords(myKeys)
```

It works. So it can't handle for some reason more than one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have "in" instead of "="

```
const string query = "FROM TableA WHERE Key in (:keys)";
```

Comment: so when do you use the "=" sign?